# programming error with pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I am attempting to query a SQL Server 2012 database using the following code:

```
import pyodbc

class sqlserverConnector:
    def __init__(self, connectionString):

        """
        this is a typical connection string using windows authentication and the DSN manager:

            'DSN=python;Trusted_Connection=yes'
        """
        self._conn = pyodbc.connect(connectionString)
        self._curs = self._conn.cursor()
        self.fetchall = self._curs.fetchall
        self.description = self._curs.description
        self.columns = dict()

    def __del__(self):
        self._conn.close()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self._curs.__iter__()

    # executes SQL statements
    def execute(self, statement, **params):
        if params is None:
            self._curs.execute(statement)
        else:
            self._curs.execute(statement,params)

        # creates a dictionary of column names and positions
        if self._curs.description != None:
            self.columns = dict((field[0], pos) for pos, field in enumerate(self._curs.description))
        else:
            None
```

And:

```
from sqlutil import *

sqlcnxn = sqlserverConnector('DSN=python;Trusted_Connection=yes')
rows = sqlcnxn.execute("select * from demographics", params=None)

for row in rows:
    print row
    break
```

The goal is to print out a single row (the table has 80k+ rows). However I always get this error message:

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')
```

I have googled around and it seems like this pops up for different people for different reasons and none of the solutions I have found fit my error. I think what is happening is that the `execute` method is defaulting to the first `else` statement instead of the first `if` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `**params` notation, then `params` is **always** a dictionary.

Calling that function with `params=None` means you now have a dictionary with:

```
>>> def func(**params):
...     print params
... 
>>> func()
{}
>>> func(params=None)
{'params': None}
>>> func(foo='bar')
{'foo': 'bar'}
```

The syntax is meant to accept arbitrary keyword parameters, illustrated by the `foo` keyword argument above.

Either remove the `**` or test for an empty dictionary, and don't set `params=None` when calling `.execute()`:

```
def execute(self, statement, **params):
    if not params:
        self._curs.execute(statement)
    else:
        self._curs.execute(statement, params)
    # ...
```

and:

```
rows = sqlcnxn.execute("select * from demographics")
```

Note that your `execute()` function has no `return` statement, which means that `rows` will be set to `None` (the default return value for functions). Add `return self` if you meant to return the connection object so that it can be iterated over.

Comment: I did not know that it always created a dictionary. Thank you. A follow up question, when I test for an empty dictionary like you recommend rows becomes None. Why is this?

Comment: @mnky9800n: Your function doesn't return anything; you forgot to `return self` at the end.